# Not getting the TItle back while Handling Frames in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Using the below code to handle a frame in selenium. The page is getting loaded however i am not getting the text of the Webelement here(in this case Title Bar (top.html))

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://londonfreelance.org/courses/frames/index.html");
    String text = driver.findElement(By.name("main")).getText();
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: whats the title you are trying to get?

Comment: Trying to get the title of the frame. If you open the given link you will see be able to see the Title Bar (top.html),. I am trying get that here.

Comment: Okay, try my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
   driver.switchTo().frame("main");
   String title = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText().split("\\(")[0];
   System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: ok got it but can you plz let me know the issue with my code?

Comment: You should switch to your target frame first  to access the contents